# 10.10 to 11.04 upgrade unmet dependencies

Tags: 11.04, apt, dependencies, plymouth, package-management

I was trying to upgrade my system from 10.10 to 11.04.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 plymouth : Depends: libdrm-nouveau1a (>= 2.4.23) but it is not installed  
            Depends: libplymouth2 (= 0.8.2-2ubuntu22) but 0.8.2-2ubuntu5.1 is installed  
 plymouth-label : Depends: libplymouth2 (= 0.8.2-2ubuntu23) but 0.8.2-2ubuntu5.1 is   installed  
                  Depends: plymouth (= 0.8.2-2ubuntu23) but 0.8.2-2ubuntu22 is installed  
 plymouth-x11 : Depends: plymouth (= 0.8.2-2ubuntu5.1) but 0.8.2-2ubuntu22 is installed  
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

---

When i do apt-get -f install, I get the same errors alongwith two more lines:

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.  
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Now, I am unable to install, remove or upgrade or do anything. How do I solve this, atleast how do i force enable my system to install, remove stuff.

MORE: I have also tried dpkg configure and also tried to purge remove plymouth for starters. But nothing works.

Update: Also, I have tried removing all the ppas which included xorg-edgers which probably has caused some issues. But not having/having that ppa in sources.list.d changes nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. The problem was that I had moved the ppa files from /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and the missing dependency was changed by one of the ppas.

So moving back the ppa was one thing.

After that, I realized that the ppa was commented and was not picking up. So I removed the comment from .list file and it is working fine now.

Comment: I think you should mark the question as answered then.

Comment: It allows to mark it answered after 2 days. Will mark it then.